# UNCSS не включает некоторые стили

Tags: css, gulp, postcss

С помощью gulp запускаю uncss для минифицированного файла

```
gulp.task('uncss', function () {

    let plugins = [
        uncss({
            html: [
                'http://hiloftdesign/',
                'http://hiloftdesign/portfolio',
                'http://hiloftdesign/services/dizayn-kvartir',
                'http://hiloftdesign/services/dizayn-domov',
                'http://hiloftdesign/contacts',
                'http://hiloftdesign/privacy-policy',
                'http://hiloftdesign/contract-offer',
                'http://hiloftdesign/thanks',
            ],
            ignore: [
                /active/,
                /.swiper*/,
                '.header--sticky',
            ]
        })
    ];

    return gulp.src('./public/css/frontend.min.css')
        .pipe(postcss(plugins))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css'));
});
```

Но почему-то после компиляции пропадают некоторые стили. Например, у класса "xl:hover-translate-up" стили стираются, хотя до компиляции они есть и работают. Такое впечатление, будто просто рандомно плагин не хочет сохранять стиль. Ошибок при компиляции нет. Порой даже ignore через регулярки не помогает. При этом правильность регулярки проверена через отладку нативного js.
Кто сталкивался с таким, как решить? Есть ignore, но и он не всегда срабатывает тут, да и вылавливать вручную каждый такой "потерянный" стиль и вручную его добавлять в игнор - не гибкое решение.